# nested lists and for loops program in python gives me a crazy result

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.3, nested-lists

I'm new in python and I have been learning list and dictionaries recently. I'm stuck in an exercise of lists inside another list (in other words, nested lists).

The idea of this program is to take these two lists:

```
listOne = list(range(1, 100))

listTwo = list(range(99, 0, -1))
```

and the program should take, for example, the element 0 of the first list and the element 0 of the second list and so on with the following numbers, the answer should be like:

```
[[1,99],[2,98],[3,97], .....]
```

This is what I have typed so far:

```
listOne = list(range(1, 100))
listTwo = list(range(99, 0, -1))
listThree = []

for x in listOne:
    for y in listTwo:
        listThree.append((x, y))

print(listThree)
```

However, when I run this program, the computer prints a huge and crazy result that takes around 5 seconds to print the result. I want this program to be the most simple as possible since I haven't learned a lot. If you have any suggestions for working with nested lists more efficiently, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: er.. element 0 of the second list is 99, not 0.  And element 0 of the first list is 1, not 0.  Your output doesn't match.

Comment: Seems like it's working fine to me.  listOne starts at 1 and goes to 99 (inclusive).  listTwo starts at 99 and goes to 1 (inclusive).  And I've got all the expected `tuple`s in the result...

Comment: @roipi so maybe what they are asking me is to print this result [[1, 99], [2, 98], ....] I don't have any idea... 

Write a program which creates and displays the following lists:
1. A list with all the integer numbers between 0 and 99
2. A list with all the integer numbers between 99 and 0
Use a loop to add element 0 of the first list with element 0 of the second list, element 1 of the first list with element 1 of the second list... and through to the end of the lists, and store the result in a third list.  Display the third list.

Comment: It looks like instead of a nested loop, you want a single loop that  progress through both listOne and listTwo at the same time, right? To do that, instead of creating a loop like
    for x in listOne:
    ....
try making a loop like this:
    for i in range(len(listOne)):
        x = listOne[i]
etc...

Comment: Instead of nesting loops, it looks like they want you to pair up corresponding elements and sum them.   You could use the `zip` function or refer to them each by index.  The point is that you're going to get a lot of 100s, and this is a common trick to sum 1+2+3..n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop tries to enumerate every possible combination of elements in listOne and listTwo.
Does the following achieve what you want(in python 2.7.6)?

`for index in range(len(listOne)):
    listThree.append((listOne[index],listTwo[index]))`

Comment: **THANK YOU!!!** This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I always code in the hardest and longest way possible. I will think about index more the next time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier would be to use list comprehension here:

```
listOne = list(range(1,100))
listTwo = list(reversed(listOne))
listThree = [[x, 100-x] for x in range(1,100)]
```

or with `zip`:

```
listThree = zip(listOne, listTwo) # tuples are results
listThree = zip(listOne, reversed(listOne)) # tuples are results
listThree = map(list, zip(listOne, listTwo)) # list are results
listThree = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(listOne, listTwo)] # list are results
```

if you don't need two first lists, you can chain this up for one-liner:

```
listThree = list(map(list, zip(range(1,100), reversed(range(1,100))))) # result is list of lists
listThree =  list(zip(range(1,100), reversed(range(1,100)))) # result is list of tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the output list you're looking for is to use the [zip function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
listOne = list(range(1, 100))
listTwo = list(range(99, 0, -1))

print(zip(listOne, listTwo))
```